# Where does Intl API get it's time zone list?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-intl

I'm relying on `Intl` to determine user's time zone.

I also want to give users a way to pick their timezone. I have a list of time zones -- some subset of Olson database.

I wanna make sure `Intl` won't give me some weird time zone I don't have in my list.

Where does Intl API get it's time zone list? Is there a way to list all of them or does it trust the browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat):

> The only value implementations must recognize is
>   "UTC"; the default is the runtime's default time zone. Implementations
>   may also recognize the time zone names of the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones),
>   such as "Asia/Shanghai", "Asia/Kolkata", "America/New_York".

Comment: Yes, but IANA time zone database does not have a plane csv list. There is kind of a list https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone1970.tab , but I fear it's not full.

Comment: What about writing a simple JavaScript program that compares your DB list to what the browser supports?

Comment: Different browsers implement different versions of the IANA db, so that's another complication... I'll post back here if I find a way to pin a specific version.